# Run Custom Tool at build in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resx, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I'm creating an internal VS template to create new versions of a multilingual website with custom fields filled by a wizard. All is going well, until I try and run the program. Upon running, I receive...

**Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "<My Namespace>.Global.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "<My program>" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.**

If I open up the resx files and save them, or choose to run a custom tool before building, it works fine, but if I try to build immediately after creating the project, I receive that error.

My settings on all of my resx files are...

- Build Action - Embedded Resource
- Copy to Output Directory - Do not coopy
- Custom Tool - PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
- Custom Tool Namespace - <My Namespace>

Mostly, I'm just looking for a way to run the custom tool at build. This does need to work as I've described it. This is a large company, and non-programmers/non-experts work here.

Thanks in advance,
Andrew